# Can I put a bed quilt/blanket in airplane's cargo?

Tags: air-travel, luggage, europe, eu, regulations

I don't want to buy an extra suitcase, and I don't really care if the quilt (if that's its name) lands damaged or not. I am thinking of adding a suitcase (luggage 23kg) in my airplane booking, and then appear in the airliner's counter and give this:

[image]

Will it be accepted? Or it is mandatory that it's enclosed in a suitcase?

Comment: Most likely so. But can't you bring that as a carry-on? It looks like it might be small enough.

Comment: Is that case as sturdy as a duffel or rather easily damaged?

Comment: @MichaelHampton most likely it will be accepted? As for bringing it as a carry-on, well I hadn't thought of that - I could give my hand luggage in the cargo and take that quilt on board - my only fear is that's probably a bit larger in the dimensions of the typical hand luggage. But to be honest I'd rather not do that, my co-passengers might feel strange if they see my boarding with that... :) But good idea as a fallback plan.

Comment: Well @Willeke it's just a minimalistic case. It might get scrambled by the suitcases in the cargo, but I mean the quilt will take the dictated form.. What it might be damaged is the zipper of the case, for which I don't really care..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've seen plenty of things on the luggage carousel that don't look like luggage and I've checked backpacks many times.

I wouldn't check exactly that, though--I would take some strong tape and tape down those handles.  Things like that that can catch on things in the system are asking for damage.

Answer (score 5):

The airlines will take it as it doesn't contain anything that is against the rules.

However, given how easy it would be to peirce the bag and damage the quilt/comforter itself, you may want to consider some extra protection. For example putting it in a heavy duty garbage bag. I check-in things regularly in a garbage bag as I often have multiple smaller items and I combine them together into one using a double garbage bag.

Comment: Ah hadn't thought of that, cool!

Comment: A garbage bag is probably not as strong as the bag it's currently in.

Comment: @LorenPechtel As I said heavy duty garbage bags (0.45mm think if I recall correctly) and I often double bag my stuff while checking them in and I've never had the inner bag peirced.